# Talking to the spdy server with java client

Tags: java, jetty, spdy

I have started a spdy proxy server using jetty9.

jetty-spdy-proxy.xml:

```
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
</New>

<New id="tlsHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
  <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
  <Call name="addCustomizer">
    <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
  </Call>
</New>

<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
      <Arg name="server"><Ref id="Server" /></Arg>
      <Arg name="factories">
        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
          <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
              <Arg name="config"><Ref id="httpConfig" /></Arg>
            </New>
          </Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
      <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
      <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="9090" /></Set>
      <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

http/1.1
      
        
      
    
    
      
        
          localhost
          
            
              http/1.1
              127.0.0.1
              9090

8080
      
    
  
  
    
      
        
          
        
        
          
        
        
          
        
        8443

This server has started normally.

```
2013-03-28 17:49:02.623:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4a734beb{/test,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-test.war-_test-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/test.war}
2013-03-28 17:49:02.911:WARN::main: async-rest webapp is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
2013-03-28 17:49:02.990:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@28245558{/async-rest,[file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-async-rest.war-_async-rest-any-/webapp/, jar:file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-async-rest.war-_async-rest-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/example-async-rest-jar-9.0.0.v20130308.jar!/META-INF/resources/],AVAILABLE}{/async-rest.war}
2013-03-28 17:49:03.061:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@b102b93{/oldContextPath,null,AVAILABLE}
2013-03-28 17:49:03.159:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@36858c07{/javadoc,file:/home/sankuai/jetty/jetty9/javadoc,AVAILABLE}
2013-03-28 17:49:03.669:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@646dee9f{/proxy,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-xref-proxy.war-_xref-proxy-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/xref-proxy.war}
2013-03-28 17:49:03.913:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4456cd93{SSL-npn}{0.0.0.0:8443}
```

In my mind, this proxy server can translate spdy to http and proxy it to the target server.

I cannot test it now because I donnot know how to talk to the proxy server with java client(not in browser). I have googled my problem but found nothing, any suggestion here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with raw SPDY is unlike anything you've likely done before.

But that being said, there are unit tests in Jetty 9 that use Jetty's [SPDYClient](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/spdy/client/SPDYClient.html) to test its own support of SPDY.  They might help you.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-spdy/spdy-http-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/spdy/server/proxy/ProxySPDYToHTTPTest.java